# Powershell - concatenating an array reference with another variable

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to concatenate a variable with a value from an array, and having problems.

The output I get is the variable value, plus the ENTIRE array, not just the desired value (index of $i).

```
$Database = "Checklist.dbo."

$ExtractTables = @("Page"
    , "HotelOwner"
    , "Hotel"
)

for ($i=0; $i -le $ExtractTables.Length – 1; $i++)  {

    write-host $Database$ExtractTables[$i]     # <<<<<<< takes ENTIRE array
}
```

My ultimate goal is to call an executable (bcp) something like this:

```
# & bcp $Database$ExtractTables[$i] out $OutputDirectory$ExtractTables[$i].txt -c -T -SCHELDEV02
```

Any pointers for a newbie?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Database = "Checklist.dbo."

$ExtractTables = @("Page"
    , "HotelOwner"
    , "Hotel"
)

for ($i=0; $i -le $ExtractTables.Length – 1; $i++)  {
    write-host "$Database$($ExtractTables[$i])"
}
```

To evaluate a sub-expression before the rest of the expression put it inside `$()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$Database = "Checklist.dbo."

$ExtractTables = @("Page"
    , "HotelOwner"
    , "Hotel"
) 

$ExtractTables | ForEach {
    write-host "$Database$_"
}
```